# Writing an image listener on android device; need debugging tips (why running out of memory?)

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to write an app that can receive sensor_msgs/Image messages on an android device.  I've modelled the code after android_tutorial_pubsub:

```
import org.ros.address.InetAddressFactory;
import org.ros.android.BitmapFromImage;
import org.ros.android.RosActivity;
import org.ros.android.views.RosImageView;
import org.ros.node.NodeConfiguration;
import org.ros.node.NodeMainExecutor;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends RosActivity {
        private RosImageView rosImageView;

        public MainActivity() {
                super("Android App", "Android App");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                rosImageView = (RosImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                rosImageView.setTopicName("/camera/rgb/image_color");
                rosImageView.setMessageType("sensor_msgs/Image");
                rosImageView.setMessageToBitmapCallable(new BitmapFromImage());
        }

        @Override
        protected void init(NodeMainExecutor nodeMainExecutor) {
                NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration = NodeConfiguration.newPublic(InetAddressFactory.newNonLoopback().getHostName());
                nodeConfiguration.setMasterUri(getMasterUri());
                nodeMainExecutor.execute(rosImageView, nodeConfiguration.setNodeName("myapp/image_listener"));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
        }
}
```

I am able to connect to the ROS master just fine:

```
~$ rosnode list
/myapp/image_listener
/rosout
```

It is properly subscribed:

```
~$ rostopic info /camera/rgb/image_color 
Type: sensor_msgs/Image

Publishers: None

Subscribers: 
 * /myapp/image_listener (http://192.168.0.116:50285)
```

When I use rosbag play on a bag file, it shows the publisher:

```
~$ rostopic info /camera/rgb/image_color 
Type: sensor_msgs/Image

Publishers: 
 * /play_1333677784320867515 (http://192.168.0.119:44669/)

Subscribers: 
 * /myapp/image_listener (http://192.168.0.116:50285)
```

But that's the end of good behavior.  The image does not appear in the image view.  Here is my res/layout/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <org.ros.android.views.RosImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Before I start rosbag play, I am able to exit the app and re-enter no problem.  Once the publishing starts, the app is pretty much frozen.

roswtf doesn't tell me anything interesting (I ran rosbag a second time, so the play node number is different).

```
~/ros_workspace/android_core/android_image_listener$ roswtf
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules

Online checks summary:

Found 2 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING Node [/myapp/image_listener] is not connected to anything
WARNING The following nodes are unexpectedly connected:
 * /play_1333678178991195080->/rosout (/rosout)
 * unknown (http://192.168.0.116:50933/)->/rosout (/rosout)
```

logcat gives me a bunch of (nonstop):

```
D/dalvikvm( 3678): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2048K, 25% free 34961K/46599K, paused 2ms+4ms
D/dalvikvm( 3678): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2048K, 25% free 34961K/46599K, paused 2ms+4ms
D/dalvikvm( 3678): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2048K, 25% free 34961K/46599K, paused 2ms+4ms
D/dalvikvm( 3678): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2048K, 25% free 34961K/46599K, paused 2ms+4ms
```

and I can get in logcat (after running rosbag a few times):

```
E/dalvikvm-heap( 3678): Out of memory on a 4021256-byte allocation.
I/dalvikvm( 3678): "New I/O client worker #1-1" prio=5 tid=16 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4090a190 self=0x1c1d18
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   | sysTid=3717 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1856392
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   | schedstat=( 8249665000 1452014000 9972 ) utm=810 stm=14 core=1
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:~118)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.ros.internal.message.ListField.deserialize(ListField.java:75)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.ros.internal.message.DefaultMessageDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultMessageDeserializer.java:47)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.ros.internal.transport.IncomingMessageQueue$Receiver.messageReceived(IncomingMessageQueue.java:57)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:100)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:754)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:302)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:317)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:299)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:214)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:80)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:754)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.messageReceived(SimpleChannelHandler.java:154)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:100)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:754)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.messageReceived(SimpleChannelHandler.java:154)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:100)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:540)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:261)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:349)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:280)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:200)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:44)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
I/dalvikvm( 3678):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
I/dalvikvm( 3678): 
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678): An exception was thrown by a user handler while handling an exception event ([id: 0x40a8e7f8, /192.168.0.116:46517 :> 192.168.0.119/192.168.0.119:58427] EXCEPTION: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678): org.ros.exception.RosRuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at org.ros.internal.transport.ConnectionTrackingHandler.exceptionCaught(ConnectionTrackingHandler.java:73)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:432)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:52)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:302)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:317)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:299)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:214)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:261)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:349)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:280)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:200)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:118)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at org.ros.internal.message.ListField.deserialize(ListField.java:75)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at org.ros.internal.message.DefaultMessageDeserializer.deserialize(DefaultMessageDeserializer.java:47)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    at org.ros.internal.transport.IncomingMessageQueue$Receiver.messageReceived(IncomingMessageQueue.java:57)
W/DefaultChannelPipeline( 3678):    ... 12 more
```

So it looks like an ArrayList was filled until it could no longer be filled.  What is doing that filling?  Why aren't my images showing up?

Can you give me an idea on how to debug this?

Sorry that this was very long.  Hopefully I provided all the relevant information.

Technical specs:

- Ubuntu 10.04 running in VMWare
- Target: android-12
- Android SDK Tools r17
- rosjava_core, android_core cloned today

EDIT: I edited the above text to say that I don't always get the exceptions.  It takes multiple time of running rosbag.  For the most part, I just see an endless stream of GC_CONCURRENT.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31342/writing-an-image-listener-on-android-device;-need-debugging-tips-(why-running-out-of-memory?)/) by [amigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2073/amigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2012-04-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please file an issue and attach a sample bag file that will cause the error. I'll try to reproduce it: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0